# Why are "Lime" and "LimeGreen" different colours in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Why do both "Lime" and "LimeGreen" exist as available colours in HTML/CSS? "LimeGreen" is a darker colour (#32CD32), more evocative of an actual lime, whereas "Lime" is the name for #00FF00, the most extreme green available.

Is there some historical reason for this?

Comment: Because `LimeGreen` tries to be a color between `Lime` and `Green`? Also because there was `#00FF00` that most certainly needed a name?

Comment: Doesn't answer how they were originally named, but the hex naming structure is based on X11 Color Names http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names

Comment: Because someone put them there. I wouldn't try to figure out the rhyme or reason behind the CSS color names.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is *not* opinion-based, it should be available from the historical record. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They come from the `rgb.txt` file in X11. It seems to be pretty hard to track down who originally put the entries for LimeGreen and Lime in that file.

See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75466/16767

Answer (score 0):

Nice Question mattybrad,

The official web color named lime actually corresponds to pure green on an RGB display. Lime green is the color of the outer skin of a lime.

But

Lime, also traditionally known as lime green, lime-green, or bitter lime, is a color that is a shade of green, so named because it is a representation of the color of the citrus fruit called limes. It is the color that is in between the web color chartreuse and yellow on the color wheel.It is of green hue and is also one of Crayola's many colors.